# Why is text element going outside of div?

Tags: html, css

Really quick question, I have researched this and tried looking up a solution but have had no luck. I am vertically aligning two texts in a div but the text inside the div always goes outside it's container and I have no idea why.

I have attached two images below. The first link is the problem, the second link is what I want it to look like.

Thank you!
[image: Problem]
[image]
CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.homepage-window {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
}

.nav-bar {
    width: 18%;
    background-color: #2E3E4E;
}

.bar-manager {
    width: 100%;
}

.top-bar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 7%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid lightgrey;
}

.top-bar p {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

.bottom-bar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    height: 9%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid lightgrey;
}

.bottom-bar h1 {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Homepage.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<head>
    <title>Cold-Ops Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="homepage-window">
        <div class="nav-bar">   
        </div>
        <div class="bar-manager">
            <div class="top-bar">
                <p>Homepage</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-bar">
                <h1>Welcome, Omard2000</h1><br>
                <p>some text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have height 9%, that is why your link falls out, delete height:9%; in your css

Comment: Edit: my bad, misread your answer. I deleted the height:9% but still no luck. Edit #2: Ended up taking away the height and wrapping the two texts in divs. Thanks!